# Can GKE on prem operate without connection to Google cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

From everything I read, Anthos (formerly GKE on-prem) seems to require a connection back to the Google cloud.

We have the need to have a kubernetes cluster with all the nice features of GKE but we need to run in an "air-gapped" network with no external Internet connections.

I cannot tell if GKE on-prem supports this.  Everything I read or see on a video indicates there is always a connection back to the Google cloud.

Can someone clarify?

Comment: Have you considered [Private Google Access](https://cloud.google.com/anthos/gke/docs/on-prem/concepts/connect-on-prem-gcp#private-google-access) for your use case?

Answer (score 2):

The GKE on-prem has a core installation of GKE functionalities of the Cluster management on-prem but requires an external connectivity to Google API just in case to take advantage of the full functionality provided by Anthos (specifically Cloud Monitoring and Cloud Logging, and Connect for registering clusters as part of an Anthos environment, allowing them to be viewed and managed in the Anthos dashboard) [1](https://cloud.google.com/anthos/docs/concepts/overview#networking_environment).
So, in theory it does not require GCP connectivity if you are not intended to use such resources.

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

Anthos (GKE on-prem) requires a connection to Google Cloud for billing, cluster creation, adding-nodes to clusters, etc.

### references

The following "Anthos technical overview" statement may be misleading :

> Anthos on-prem : With Anthos clusters on VMware, all components are hosted in the customer's on-prem virtualization environment.
> One should understand that all run-time components are hosted on-premise, including the Kubernetes master.

However, **the page [Impact of temporary disconnection from Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/anthos/docs/concepts/anthos-connectivity)** states:

Connected by design:

> Even when an Anthos cluster runs on-premises, it is designed to have a permanent connection to Google Cloud for a number of reasons, including monitoring and management (excerpt from this [page]

Connected for billing:

> Anthos metering information is required for compliance as stated in the Service Specific Terms for "Premium Software".

Connected for some important administration tasks:

> "You cannot create clusters." ... "you cannot add a new node to a cluster when disconnected" ...

Other interesting pages:

- [Proxy and firewall rules] (https://cloud.google.com/anthos/clusters/docs/on-prem/latest/how-to/firewall-rules)
- [Firewall rules for user cluster nodes](https://cloud.google.com/anthos/clusters/docs/on-prem/latest/how-to/firewall-rules#firewall_rules_for_user_cluster_nodes)

Google also provide a [preflight checks](https://cloud.google.com/anthos/clusters/docs/on-prem/latest/how-to/preflight-checks#list) tools that to validates internet access to required domains and validates proxy configuration...